# How to change styles while route changing in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router

When route(react-route) changing, how can I load or remove the styles relevant to the new page? I really don't know who is in charge of this function , react or webpack or react-router. But now, when the home page loaded, all of the styles in project will load, how could I do?

```
Routes: 

<Router history={hashHistory}>
 <IndexRoute component={HomePage}/>
 <Route path="/page1" component={Page1}/>
 <Route path="/page2" component={Page2}/>
</Router>

Page1: 

 import './page1style.css';
 export default class Page1 extends React.Component {}

Page2: 
  import './page2style.css';
  export default class Page2 extends React.Component {}
```

Like the code, when I visit 'http://localhost:8080'(i.e. HomePage), `page1style.css` and `page2style.css` will load, but I still not visit `page1` and `page2`.

Comment: Can you post some code that you may already have? Also, are you using any theme for example material-ui etc

Comment: @XPLOT1ON I have used `antd design`, but I don't think it's matter. Does react project have the problem - when home page loaded, all of the styles will load?

Comment: by using webpack u can do load components when needed, here is the link : **https://blog.lavrton.com/progressive-loading-for-modern-web-applications-via-code-splitting-fb43999735c6**

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for? Style for components 
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#style
Notice the html background-image has been replace with backgroundImage in react, without dash (-)

Comment: but first please share your code. Thanks

Comment: @Muhaimin Ok, I have added some code^_^

Comment: @XPLOT1ON Thanks, but It's not helpful, because all of styles are in css files. You can take a look at the codeline I newly added.

Answer (score 0):

change it like this

Page1:

```
 import style from './page1style.css';
 export default class Page1 extends React.Component {
   render () {
     return <div className={style.someClass} />
   }
 }
```

what your code does is to load as general css and that's why it load all of it. This way would be more modular and easy to handle

Comment: do you use webpack as your bundler?

Comment: yes, I do, I have tried `css-loader` moduler, but it's not work.

Comment: did you replace `someClass` with the name you specified in your css?