# CSS not changing when using React Router to route to another component

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router-dom

When I route my app to another component by using [react-router-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom), the CSS doesn't change.

This is a minimalistic version of the code to demonstrate

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Home from './Home';

function App() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Home></Home>
      </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './Home.css';

const Home = () => {
    return (
        <h1>Home</h1>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

**Home.css**

```
body {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

**Dashboard.js**

import React from 'react';
import './Dashboard.css';

```
import React from 'react';
import './Dashboard.css';

const Dashboard = () => {
    return (
        <div className='content'>
            <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

**Dashboard.css**

```
.content {
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <div>
        <Route exact path='/' component={App} />
        <Route path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
        </div>
    </Router>, document.getElementById('root'));

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
// Learn more about service workers: ...
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

When I do /dashboard, it loads the Dashboard component, but it keeps the previous CSS that was loaded from the Home component that resides the App component. The background stays blue. I want that when I route to another component because I changed the URL, it loads whatever CSS that new component has attached to it and gets rid of whatever CSS was before. Is that possible?

**Edit**: I have made an example in CodeSandbox to illustrate. It's a little different from the code above due to the limitations of the playground, but the functionality is the same.

[image: Edit frosty-cerf-s3dl3]

From what can be seen, importing as a module ends up importing it globally. If we comment the line `import Home from "./Home";` the blue background disappears. Just importing the component, imports the whole CSS despite the CSS being imported in a modular way. I'm not sure if I am missing something.

**Edit 2:**

Here are the different solutions I tried:

1. **CSS Modules**, but the **body** style was still globally loaded.
2. **Styled components** don't let me modify the **body** or **html** selectors CSS. They require me to create a **`<div>`** element and
   then have that  element span the whole body which I would style
   as if it was the body. Which is a workaround I don't want to use because for that I rather use CSS Modules for the whole body spanning .
3. **Inline styling** also doesn't let me modify the **body** or **html** selectors CSS. I would also need to use a workaround like a body spanning `<div>` as in Styled components.

Comment: i think you need the `<Switch><Router /></Switch>` so only a single route will be rendered at a time

Comment: Yeah, you're going to want the Switch component, otherwise the `/` component and the `/dashboard` component will both be rendered. Although I don't believe this is relevant to the styling issue.

Comment: CSS is not stateful.  You need to namespace your CSS to only style component elements you want to style.

Comment: I used <Router><Switch><Route ....>...</Route></Switch></Router>, because it errored out saying I should not use Switch outside of Router, but it still loads the Home blue background when I'm on the Dashboard. @AlexW by namespacing you mean I will have to use SASS or LESS?

Comment: No I mean it's normally a convention to add a class to your App component and then select/style children using the top level selector, e.g. <App className="App" /> and then `.App { background-color: #000000; } .App h1 { color: green; }`, etc.  SASS or LESS would make it easier to manage due to mixins.

Answer (score 2):

## The problem

When you import a css like you're doing here

```
import './Home.css';
```

you're importing it in a global scope, which means it will not disappear once imported.

---

## The solutions

#### CSS Modules

What you want is either [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules), which is used like this:

```
import styles from './Home.css';

<a className={styles.myStyleClass}>Hello</a>
```

#### Styled components

or a CSS-in-js framework such as [styled components](https://www.styled-components.com/) which is used like this:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const MyStyledElement = styled.a`
    color: blue;
`;

<MyStyledElement>Hello</MyStyledElement>
```

#### Regular objects / inline styling

or just "regular" CSS-in-js like:

```
const myStyle = {
    color: blue;
}

<a style={myStyle}>Hello</a>
```

---

There are plenty of options when it comes to styling, these alternatives are popular ones that I encourage you to explore and see which you enjoy.

Comment: A quick question. Does CSS Modules really work for scoping the css used when a component is loaded? I tried it, but doing `import styles from './Home.css';` loads it globally as well. Even if I don't use the style variable for anything, the background of the body is still blue when navigating to other routes. I just found a similar question, but like the OP, it didn't work for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45228589/how-to-change-styles-while-route-changing-in-react

Comment: I have added a CodeSandbox sample to my question to show what I am getting when using CSS Modules. I am not sure if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more tests I have concluded that as of now it is not possible to change whatever CSS styles have been applied to a **`<body>`** or **`<html>`** selector in an React SPA when a CSS file is already loaded and one uses React Router to render other components. I still appreciate the answers and the time taken to help me find a solution. They are still valid answers if we are not talking about the **`<body>`** or **`<html>`** node in an HTML document. From them I learned about other ways to use CSS in React. I modified the original post with the solutions I tried.

What ended working was modifying the DOM styles with JavaScript whithin the component itself.

**Home.js**

```
import React from "react";

const Home = () => {
  // Modify the DOM Styles with JavaScript
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";

  // Or uncomment below to modify the
  // document root background color
  // which in this case would be <html>

  //document.bgColor = "blue";

  // Or modify the root tag style of the document instead of the
  // <body> (<html> in this case)

  //document.documentElement.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: green');

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <form action="/dashboard">
        <input type="submit" value="Go to Dashboard" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Here is a working example:

[image: Edit elastic-dawn-4stoi]